# Editing Key value in dictionary of a csv in order to perform the following

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary, key

I apologise for the poor title given to this question, however it is difficult to explain with out the code. I am trying to get my code to do the following; if the rank key is 2 and the numeric key is anything (blank, numeric,or other), and if for the previous row is rank key 1 and numeric key 1 then continue to next line OF the script.

However I cant seem to get the code to yield what it should despite numerous efforts. The line of code that requires attention is line 14, but I thought it best to provide some background code to set the context.

#### Example data

```
Unique Name,Rank,100% OmNTS,Numeric
xyz,1,10.2,1
xyz,2,12.5,-
xyz,3,18.8,2
xyz,4,25.9,
pmz,1,29.8,1
pmz,2,200.9,5
pmz,3,210.9,
pmz,4,250.89,
pmz,5,290.9685,
xyz2,1,10.9,1
xyz2,2,12.59,3
xyz2,3,18.8,2
xyz2,4,25.9,,
pmz2,1,29.8,,
pmz2,2,200.9,5
pmz2,3,210.9,
pmz2,4,250.89,
pmz2,5,290.9685,
```

#### Code snippet:

```
for counter, row in enumerate(reader):
counter += 1
if counter != 1:
    for field in fields[3:]:
        if field == "Numeric" or field == "Rank":
            row[field] = row[field] and float(row[field])
        if field == "Rank":
            row[field] = row[field] and int(row[field])

    key = (row['Rank'], row['Numeric'])
    previous = entries[row['Unique Name']]


    if (key[0] == 2) and (1 <= key[1] <= 50 or key[1] is None) and ((1, 1) in previous):
        p = previous[(1, 1)]
        print 'test data text {r[Rank]} test {p[Rank]} test {r[100% OmNTS]} test {p[100% OmNTS]} '.format(r=row, p=p)
```

We would hope for a match in row 2, where the elements in row 3 (including title row in count) where the elements of row 2  would be stored as previous. The same thing for row 7 and 12, however this Key reference would ignore row 16 since row 15 was not (1,1)

#### Desired Output

```
test data text 2 test 1 test 12.5 test 10.2
test data text 2 test 1 test 200.9 test 29.8
test data text 2 test 1 test 12.59 test 10.9
```

Many thanks in advance for taking the time to look at my problem. 
AEA

Comment: First of all you should correct the indentation. Other than that example input would be a nice addition.

Comment: and can you tell us exactly what in going wrong? Are you getting errors?  Is it not entering the if statement?  always entering the if  statement?

Comment: Making a simple example as we speak.

Comment: There was an answer, however it has been deleted I will quickly try the proposed fix before finishing the example.

Comment: It was mine, and after I posted it I decided it was wrong (I was surprised that `1<None` does not raise an error).

Comment: @tcaswell: that's one of those unorderable type issues that was fixed in 3.

Comment: When i fisrt started coding (i started in python about 4 months ago) I was advised to use 2.7 as oppose to 3, because some librarys were not supported in 3

Comment: added some simple example data that could go with this example.

Comment: Made some edits to the post to show example data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some areas where your coding could be wrong:

- If you have some code that should print the correct output but doesn't, it could be that the csv reader or file object iterator was exhausted. Might you be working in an interactive shell, you should open the file and initialize the reader object each time before you run your loop.
- An empty field is represented by an empty string, not by `None`.
- From your code snippet it is unclear what `reader`, `fields` and `entries` are, perhaps there are some bugs in there as well.

My own attempt using the csv module:

```py
from csv import DictReader

with open('example.csv') as f:
    check = False
    for row in DictReader(f):
        n = row['Numeric'].replace('-', '')
        r = row['Rank']

        if check and r == '2' and (not n or 1 <= float(n) <= 50):
            s = row['100% OmNTS'], omnts_p
            print 'test data text 2 test 1 test %s test %s' % s

        elif r == n == '1':
            check = True
            omnts_p = row['100% OmNTS']

        else:
            check = False
```

I hope this is sort of what you want. It does print the desired output:

```
test data text 2 test 1 test 12.5 test 10.2
test data text 2 test 1 test 200.9 test 29.8
test data text 2 test 1 test 12.59 test 10.9
```

Answer (score 4):

Was a bit confusing to udnerstand but i gave it a shot.

```
f = open('data.txt')

# Will hold previous loop's values
tmp = []

# Start the loop
for line in f:
    list = line.split(',')

    name = list[0]
    rank = list[1]
    omnts = list[2]
    numeric = list[3].strip() # remove newlines

    if numeric and rank == '2' and  tmp:
        if tmp[1] == '1' and tmp[3] == '1':
            print "test data text {} test {} test {} test {}".format(rank, tmp[0], omnts, tmp[2])

    # Store this loop's values so we can check in the next iteration
    tmp = [name, rank, omnts, numeric]
```

Outputs:

```
test data text 2 test 1 test 12.5 test 10.2
test data text 2 test 1 test 200.9 test 29.8
test data text 2 test 1 test 12.59 test 10.9
```

Comment: ps: this assumes that the data.txt file does not contain the the row "Unique Name,Rank,100% OmNTS,Numeric"